# Australian getting a China visa in Kuala Lumpur

Tags: visas, china, australian-citizens, kuala-lumpur

I'm planning to go from Kuala Lumpur to China. Is it easy for an Australian to get a Chinese visa in Kuala Lumpur ? What documents do I need ? How long does it take ? And how long can I get a visa for?

Comment: Hi Nick welcome to Travel.SE. What research have you already done ?

Answer (score 1):

**No** (Unless you are a resident of Malaysia and can proof so). You should apply in Australia or your country of residence.

[The Malaysia site of VisaForChina](http://www.visaforchina.org/KUL_EN/) has a step-by-step guide and when you complete that you will find a list of requirements:

> (3) Proof of legal status (applicable for those not applying for the visa in their country of citizenship)
>   If you are not applying for a visa in the country of your citizenship, you must provide the original and photocopy of your valid certificates of residence, employment or student status, or other valid certificates of legal stay provided by the relevant authorities of the country where the Visa Centre is located.

If you are just travelling through Malaysia that will likely not convince the visa officers. China does apply this policy world-wide that you should apply from your country of citizenship or residence (an exception existed at least in the past through HK) so a change of itinerary won't alter your result.

Comment: Another exception is EU Citizens in EU countries...

Comment: @jacoman891 I wasn't aware of this, great to know. Do you have a link to details / a source for that?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no. I saw a sourced recent answer to that effect here on Travel.SE, but I can't seem to dig it up again. It's not a matter of universal policy, but the fact that most embassies accept an EU passport as a "certificate of legal stay"...

Comment: I emailed the Chinese Visa Service Center in the UK about EU citizens. Their response is [here](http://pastebin.com/ErwkuZ1i).

Comment: @jacoman891 great stuff. make that an own Q&A, ping me in chat and you have +15 from me

Comment: It's already documented [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61114/proof-of-legal-status-for-applying-for-a-chinese-visa-in-united-kingdom)